# How to group a list and display a inner list in a datatable by linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Hi I have a list like below

```
var data2 = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new
            {
                SubTask = x.Field<string>("subtask"),
                Name = x.Field<string>("FirstName"),
                Date = x.Field<string>("Day") + ", " + x.Field<string>("Date"),
                Hour = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(x.Field<System.Byte[]>("EmpHours"))
            });
```

My list is like below

```
Name   Date           Hour        Subtask
----    ------      -------      ----------
a      2018-11-01       1            task1
a      2018-11-01       2           task2
b      2018-11-01      'PTO'        'PTO'
c       2018-11-01      5            design
c       2018-11-01      3            coding
```

I want to group by date and name and display the result in a innerlist inside the main list.

I wanted to group by date and name and then sum the hour column for each name.
The hour column is string type 'It may contain string 'PTO' or number like '2'.

I tried below query

```
var data2 = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new
            {
                SubTask = x.Field<string>("subtask"),
                Name = x.Field<string>("FirstName"),
                Date = x.Field<string>("Day") + ", " + x.Field<string>("Date"),
                Hour = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(x.Field<System.Byte[]>("EmpHours")),
                EmpList=  (from grp in dt.AsEnumerable()
                           .GroupBy(row => new {
                               Name = row.Field<string>("Name"), 
                               Date = row.Field<string>("Date") 
                           }).Select(g => new { Date = g.Key.Date, Name = g.Key.Name, Hour = g.Sum(i => i.Field<decimal>("Hour"));

            })

 I want output like below table 




  Name   Date           Hour        Subtask
    ----    ------      -------      ----------
    a      2018-11-01      3           task1.task2    
    b      2018-11-01      'PTO'       'PTO'
    c       2018-11-01      8          design,coding
```

can anyone help me on this?

Comment: what's exactly the problem you're having? what are you getting now? what do you expect instead?

Comment: So when `Hour` contains "PTO" how do you want to sum it? Just ignore it (ie treat it as zero)? Your second example also refers to a field `Name` but your first example didnt have it - its `FirstName`

Comment: @Jamiec , If it is PTO, show as 'PTO' in the hour column no need to sum.

Comment: @sandeep.mishra I think you're missing the point - The *string* "PTO" is entirely incompatible with a numeric value which is the result of a `Sum`

Comment: I have modified my question.Please check now and let me know if it is clear to you

Comment: @sandeep.mishra Yep a bit clearer check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you're trying to do will require you to know if `Hour` is numeric and also group on that. The below would seem to do what you're after

```
 var result = data.GroupBy(x => new { 
                   x.Name,                                  // Group on Name
                   x.Date,                                  // And date
                   IsHourNumeric=x.Hour.All(Char.IsNumber)  // And whether Hour is numeric
             })
            .Select(g => new {
              Name = g.Key.Name,
              Date = g.Key.Date,
              Hour = g.Key.IsHourNumeric 
                       ? g.Select(x => int.Parse(x.Hour)).Sum().ToString() // If hour was numeric sum
                       : g.First().Hour, // Otherwise just take the first item ?!?
              SubTasks = g.Select(x => x.SubTask)
            });
```

A live example with your data is here: https://rextester.com/DPJZUH68065

Answer (score 0):

apply linq group by after your initial results (added .TOList())

```
var data2 = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new
        {
            SubTask = x.Field<string>("subtask"),
            Name = x.Field<string>("FirstName"),
            Date = x.Field<string>("Day") + ", " + x.Field<string>("Date"),
            Hour = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(x.Field<System.Byte[]>("EmpHours"))
        }).ToList();
```

Now apply group by to this result like below example:

```
var result = data2.GroupBy(n => new { n.Name, n.Date})
        .Select(cl => new Result
        {
            Name = cl.First().Name,
            Date = cl.First().Date,
            Hours = cl.Sum(c => c.Hour),
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: but Hour column is string and may contain value 'PTO'